# Как обновить данные DataGridView из другой формы в С#?

Tags: c#

Облазил много форумов в поисках этого вопроса, но к сожалению так и ничего путного не нашел.

Из дочерней формы newZakaz вызывал обновление Grid'a

Делал разными способами, например таким:

```
Dispether disp = new Dispether
disp.заказыTableAdapter.Fill(taxi_DataSet.Заказы);
```

`заказыTableAdapter и taxi_DataSet` естественно `public`, но увы никак не хочет обновляться.

Подскажите добрые люди, как всё-таки обновить этот DataGridView.

Comment: Отвечаю на свой же вопрос.
Просто на материнской форме поставил обработчик активации формы

private void Dispetcher_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
this.заказыTableAdapter.Fill(this.taxi_DataSet.Заказы);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменение другой формы происходит следующим образом:

```
Form2 testDialog2 = new Form2();
testDialog2.Text = "Редактирование записи";
```

Что касается обновления грида, тут могу привести свой пример своего кода:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/BD.mdb");
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.CommandText = "Select * from "+comboBox1.Text;
            conn.Open();
            adap.SelectCommand = com;
            adap.Fill(ds);            
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Вызывая Form1_Load обновляем грид.